# Recreate the "thin" font that iCloud Beta is using

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm looking to recreate the "Sign in to iCloud" text on http://beta.icloud.com

I have already copied all the styles attributed to that line of text, and everything is in order apart from the thickness of the text. I see Apple has applied the font-weight 300 to the style, which should and does make it thinner, however when I copy and paste the exact same code my browser renders it thicker on my own webpage. My question is, how is Apple making the text thin like that or how can I achieve the same effect?

The code from them that I have used so far is:

```
position: absolute;
color: #FFF;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 40px;
top: 131px;
font-size: 35px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.2;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Any ideas on what could be causing it to render at normal thickness? I have no conflicting styles and this is the only code relating to my line of text

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS given I can get the same style as on iCloud website. (http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/WznR5/)

[image: Text rendered in Chrome]

After font-weight, the property that can slightly change the appearance of text on webkit browsers is `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`. If you don't use it, the browser fallback to the default smoothing mode (`subpixel-antialiased`) and result in a text looking bolder.

Are you sure you've included it in your tests and your browser apply it?

Comment: The strange thing is in my browser (Chrome, latest version) that jsfiddle you posted is still thick. It doesn't look like the image you posted at all. Yet the official iCloud website shows fine and thin. Very strange. I think I'll have to go with Avenir as suggested above :/

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: iCloud imports the font «Helvetica Neue» as webfont. On the Mac you get «Helvetica Neue» from Apple by default, but not so on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try Avenir Ultra Light it's a thin font that looks similar to it

http://www.typophile.com/node/42590